# Shell script. How to kill java process and then start it again with nohup

Tags: java, shell, ubuntu, sh, nohup

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
file_name=$1
#Clear log file
echo > nohup.out 
for PID in $(ps aux | grep service_name | awk {'print $2'}); do
    kill -9 $PID;
done
echo "Killed old process"
nohup java -Xms256m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -jar $file_name &
echo "Started new process"
```

But it's just printing "Killed" and doesn't start it again.
If I do all this stuff separately - it's working, but for all together - not...

Допоможіть хто зможе...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script from which you execute it, does it contain "service_name" in its name? Then it obviously fulfills the criteria for begin killed by your for loop and commits suicide.

If it does not, then still the `grep service_name` remains which fulfills the kill criteria (has service_name in its cmd line) - for fixed strings in grep I usually write them `grep "s[e]rvice_name"`, other prefer to put another `|grep -v grep` into the pipe before the awk

Comment: How about `fgrep` / `grep -F` for fixed strings? https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs

Comment: @Johannes, the point is about grepping a string from the `ps` output without grepping the grep itself -  when you `grep "service_[n]ame"` then in the output of the ps there will be `grep service_[n]ame` and that is **not** matched by the regex service_[n]ame, so you _only_ have all other processes showing service_name